# Atom editor, Markdown: Create and open a link to another file from edit mode?

Tags: markdown, atom-editor

In the Atom editor, I've created two Markdown files, `file-a.md` and `file-b.md`, both of which are saved in the same folder on my local filesystem. I'd like to create a link from file-a to file-b, which I can follow directly from the edit window (without opening a rendered "preview"  of the Markdown document in another pane or window).

I've tried adding the following text to file-a.md:

```
[Link test](file-b.md)
```

The Atom editor does appear to recognize this as a link; the text `file-b.md` is rendered with an underline in the editor's inline formatting. When I right click on that link, one of the context menu options is "Open Link".

However, when I select "Open Link" from the context menu, nothing happens. (It's a silent failure; there's no error message, and no documents are opened.)

I've also tried, without success:

- Left-clicking the link
- Cmd-clicking the link
- Enclosing the filename in the link in quotes
- Specifying that the file is in the current directory, i.e. `./file-b.md`

I found an older (2015) post on the discuss.atom.io forum that asks for something similar to what I'm trying to do here: https://discuss.atom.io/t/clickable-links-in-markdown-file/15130. However, that post suggests installing a pair of addons, "hyperclick" and "hyperlink-hyperclick". I'm not sure whether that information is still current.

How can I add and follow a link to another local file from a Markdown file in the Atom editor?